# OpenCV histogram of an irregular shape

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm comparatively new to OpenCV. I was wondering if it is possible to get histogram of a contour (which can be a perfect rectangular or irregular in shape) found by findcontour.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

This is what exactly I'm trying to achieve. I want to analyse area in contour to detect defects (by analyzing histogram of an area ?) and declare piece defective or good. Images attached.

Good sample. (Contour detected is outlined in gray color)

[image]

Defective sample. (defect around top left corner)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want the histogram of the pixels enclosed by the contour?

Comment: Quick guidance: 1) use your contours to create a mask using `drawContours`, 2) supply your mask as the 4th parameter to `calcHist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may probably misuse the histogram.

`Contour` of an image should be a binary-valued, color-less matrix **which does not represent grayscale-level of pixels, but the boundaries**.
Meanwhile, `histogram` is a tool for analyzing how grayscale-valued of pixels distribute in your 2D image, isn't it?

Thus, why you want to profile the `histogram` of a binary-valued matrix which might not help you analyzing the image? Histogram is not the right t ool for the contour analysis though.

What you may get from the histogram should just be only a two-bar histogram because the contoured matrix contains only binary values. This might not be helpful for analysis.

Comment: While you are right about misusing part, lets say I would still want to do it, ie. getting two bar histogram. How can I do it ?

Comment: You need to draw the contour sequence on an image (or matrix) whose size is as same as the original image. You'll get a binary-valued matrix you can use for projection.

Ref: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours

Answer (score 1):

Here's an other way, using morphological operations.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

cv::Mat make_element(int morph_size, int elem_type)
{
    cv::Size sz{2*morph_size+1, 2*morph_size+1};
    cv::Point pt{morph_size, morph_size};
    cv::Mat element{getStructuringElement(elem_type, sz, pt)};
    return element;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string fn{argv[1]};
    cv::Mat src{cv::imread(fn)}, dst, mask[3];

    if (!src.data) {
        std::cerr << "No image data :(" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Clean out noise
    cv::Mat elem1{make_element(5, cv::MORPH_RECT)};
    cv::morphologyEx(src, dst, cv::MORPH_OPEN, elem1);

    // Close the hole, then XOR with original
    cv::Mat elem2{make_element(45, cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE)};
    morphologyEx(dst, dst, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, elem2);
    cv::bitwise_xor(src, dst, dst);

    // Clean out noise (again)
    cv::Mat elem3{make_element(1, cv::MORPH_RECT)};
    cv::morphologyEx(dst, dst, cv::MORPH_OPEN, elem3);

    // Mark the hole
    cv::split(dst, mask);
    cv::bitwise_xor(src, dst, dst, mask[0]);

    // Overlay
    cv::split(dst, mask);
    cv::Mat empty{dst.size(), CV_8UC1};
    std::vector<cv::Mat> v{empty, empty, mask[0]};
    cv::merge(v, dst);
    cv::bitwise_or(src, dst, dst);

    cv::namedWindow("Defect (ESC to quit)", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::startWindowThread();
    cv::imshow("Defect (ESC to quit)", dst);
    while (true) {
        int k = cv::waitKey(100) & 0xff;
        if (k == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
};
```

Some additional reading:

- Shapiro/Stockman, Finding gear defects, [Chapter 3](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse576/book/ch3.pdf)
- OpenCV [morphology tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)